# Question about simple past

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

If someone said: I wore a dress.
Could the person still be wearing the dress?

Comment: What do *you* think? Why or why not? What is your understanding here? What is the broader context? Why would this be decidable?

Comment: I think if someone said it using simple past then the wearing is finished and the person no longer wears the dress?

Comment: Are you aware of our sister site for [ell.se]?

Comment: @Jasper You're close. The simple past is finished, and *has nothing to do with the present*, so that person might be wearing a dress or might not. So yes, the person *could* still be wearing a dress. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

If one says:

> I wore a dress.

That implies that the wearing took place in the past. But it in no way implies that a similar event is not also in the present.

For example:

> I wore a dress last Tuesday. I am wearing it again today.

Or perhaps:

> I wore a dress last Tuesday, snd I am still wearing it.

Comment: you have a couple of minor typos in there. I tried to fix, but can't fix if it is less than six chars.

Comment: @Fraser Orr Thank you. Fixed now, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

'I wore a dress' does not imply that I am still wearing it.

I wore a dress- simple past tense (action/wearing is finished)

The simple past is used for a complete action in the past. The simple past does not talk about the present.

**I wore a dress** (three years ago). It does not imply that I am still wearing it. (I must have taken it off)

'I was wearing a dress (past continuous/progressive)' means that I did not take it off.

I am wearing a dress (present continuous/progressive) denotes that I am still wearing it.

We can say, 'I wore a dress this morning/yesterday and I am still wearing it'.